# broadcastEval function to fetch roles from a guild is returning duplicate roles from all shards...(Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have two functions that are called when my bot is added to a server. One fetches the guilds channels and one fetches the guilds roles.

I have recently implemented sharding within my environment, and when editing my channel and role fetching functions using broadcastEval() from the ShardingManager with Discord.js (Im running v14.7.1) I am getting duplication of roles, where it is returning roles multiplied by the amount of shards, to indicate the guild is accessible on each shard which shouldn't be the case.

My fetch channels function works fine and does return on one set of channels (not duplicated) from one shard the guild is located on.

It's almost exactly the same function:

Here is the fetch roles function:

```js
export const getShardRoles = async (guildId) => {
      const roles = await client.shard.broadcastEval(
        async (client, context) => {
          try {
            const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(context.guildId, false, true);
            if (guild) {
              const roles = guild.roles.cache
                .filter((role) => role.name !== "@everyone")
                .map((role) => ({ id: role.id, name: role.name }));
              console.log(`Shard ID: ${client.shard.ids[0]}, Roles:`, roles);
              return roles;
            }
          } catch (error) {
            // Guild not found on this shard
          }
        },
        { context: { guildId } }
      );
      console.log("Roles:", roles);
      return roles.flat();
    };
```

This function currently returns all roles but from each shard?

What am I missing? How is my channels function working as expected, but my roles function is acting weird?

This is my fetch channels function that works as expected for reference:

````
  const channels = await client.shard.broadcastEval(
    async (client, context) => {
      try {
        const guild = await client.guilds.fetch(context.guildId);
        if (guild) {
          return guild.channels.cache
            .filter((channel) => channel.type === 0 || channel.type === 5)
            .map((channel) => ({ id: channel.id, name: channel.name }));
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(
          "No guild channels found with id on any shard:",
          context.guildId,
          error
        );
      }
    },
    { context: { guildId } }
  );
  console.log("Channels:", channels);
  return channels.flat();
};```
````